# On Soap UI is there a way of counting how may times a particular value occurs

Tags: soapui

I'm trying to count the number of times a document name appears in my SOAP UI assertion

I've followed the instruction's under the question "SoapUI how to check the count of number of items returned in response" and that works fine (`count(//*:myRoot/*:list/*:element)`), but it only counts how many documents exist. I need to count how many times the same document name appears.

I'm sure it must be a XPath assertion, but still haven't figured it out.

I've love some help if anyone knows how to do it

Comment: Just a guess off the top of my head: `count(//*:myRoot/*:list/*:element/text() = "document name")`